# Crash in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am getting a crash at random.
I dont know the reason because the log report is not showing any line number.
I think I am getting this crash in a listview.

I have attached this listview below a relative Layout. And I am setting visibility of listview as per the records.

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2357)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:697)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Please help me get rid of this crash.

Code:

```
searchEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    placesTask = new PlacesTask();
                    placesTask.execute(s.toString());
                }
            }
        });

private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<TextSearchPlace>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected List<TextSearchPlace> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<TextSearchPlace> places = null;

            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser(getActivity());

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<TextSearchPlace> result) {
            autocompletePlaces = result;
            if (searchLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                try {
                    if (result != null && result.size() > 0) {
                        rootView.findViewById(R.id.dummy_iv).setVisibility(
                                View.VISIBLE);
                        suggestionLv.setAdapter(new PlaceSuggestionListAdapter(
                                getActivity(), result));
                        suggestionLv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        rootView.findViewById(R.id.dummy_iv).setVisibility(
                                View.GONE);
                        suggestionLv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am showing list if i am getting result and hiding list if no result found.

My Adapter -

```
public class PlaceSuggestionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    List<TextSearchPlace> places;

    public PlaceSuggestionListAdapter(Context mContext,
            List<TextSearchPlace> places) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.places = places;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return places.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (mContext != null) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.place_list_item, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.nameTv = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            UtilFunction.labelTypeFace(holder.nameTv, mContext.getAssets());
            holder.nameTv.setText(places.get(pos).getName());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView nameTv;
    }

}
```

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference` When are you calling `setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor()` in your code?

Comment: Please post  the relevant code .

Comment: Without code, it is difficult to find out the issue

Comment: asked many times ... do not return `null` from `getView` of your `Adapter` implementation ...

Comment: @Selvin Iam not returning null in my adapter.

Comment: @PiyushGupta attached.

Comment: just few small tips: 1. let `getItem(int arg0)` return `places.get(arg0)` 2. `getItemId`  should returns `arg0`, too 3. checking if (mContext != null) is unnecesery (you can even change `Context mContext;` to `final Context mContext;`) the getView implementation look good ... are you using another adapter in the same fragment/activity ... this code look good for me

Comment: @Selvin No. This is the only adapter I am using

Comment: @Selvin Can you tell why I am getting this crash?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are returning a null view in getView, mContext might be null. Don't store references to Context. Use View.getContext() in the getView() in the Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

did you solve this?
I get exactly the save logcat dump.
In my case when I try to have more than 3 entries in the arraylist used by the adapter. Tried changed to different types of layout. No luck.

But I found my own very, very embarrassing error right 5 minutes ago.
My Adapter.getView() returned null (a three day old debug test line left...) but the logcat starts at Main and stops at AbsListView.obtainView() so there was not too much pointing towards my getView().

Comment: This isn't really an answer. If you have a question please leave on comment on the OP instead, unless you actually have a solution.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I tried, but was told that I needed 50 reputations to comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a need to carefully review the problem.
I there is the cause of this problem.

getView() return null.